# Validate data exits using EF core best practices

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

List list = new List();

I have a list of Guid. What is the best to check all guid exits or not using ef core table?

I am currently using the below code but the performance is very bad. assume user table as 1 million records.

**for Example**

```
public async Task<bool> IsIdListValid(IEnumerable<int> idList)  
{
   var validIds = await _context.User.Select(x => x.Id).ToListAync();
   return idList.All(x => validIds.Contains(x));
}
```

Comment: There is no best practices without third party extensions. If you ok to use them, I'll prepare sample using [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

Answer (score 0):

The performance is bad because you are reading each row of the table into memory, and then iterating through it (`ToList` materializes the query.) Try using the `Any()` method to take advantage of the strength of the database. Use something like the following: `bool exists = _context.User.Any(u => idList.Contains(u));`. This should translate to an SQL IN clause.

Comment: His current solution isn't that bad, he's not loading all entities into memory, only their IDs (using `Select(x => x.Id)`. Also, his logic is to check that *all* items are present, your example would pass if only 1 ID existed.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you assert that the # of IDs being sent in is kept reasonable, you could do the following:

```
var idCount = _context.User.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.Id)).Count();
return idCount == idList.Count;
```

This assumes that you are comparing on a unique constraint like the PK. We get a count of how many rows have a matching ID from the list, then compare that to the count of IDs sent.

If you're passing a large # of IDs, you would need to break the list up into reasonable sets as there are limits to what you can do with an IN clause and potential performance costs as well.